# Compare two arrays in different columns in a file and print matching elements for every row using unix

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I have a tabulated file like

col1   col2   6 29 61 63 67 70 133 134 150 159 166 208 220 260 261 262 303 312 316 327 330 349 378 387 396 408 415 454 465    V       260 135 49 159

and so on up to thousand rows.

divided in five columns. I have converted third and fifth column in arrays by means of split (space delimiter) in order to compare both of them and print matching numbers. However I have tried different ways without results by the following code

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} { allpos=split($3,arr1," "); posSNP=split($5,arr2," "); { for (j in arr2) {for (i in arr1) { if ( arr2[j] == arr1[i]) {printf "%s ", i arr1[i]}} printf "\n"}}}' "input" > "output";
```

and similar codes.

My desired output and would be something like:

col1 col2 V: 159 - 260

How can I get it in unix environment? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please format your question so the input and output data are more understandable. How many columns are there? Also, you need to describe how to compute the output.

Comment: the input is a tabulated file.tsv in which there are five columns. the third and fifth column are a set of numbers and would be compare all numbers between them for every row into the file and print matching numbers in the output.tsv file. In summary, the first and second column remain in the output. tsv file in the same way and the third column will be the matching numbers separated for every row. I hope I explain more correctly the input.tsv file and the desired output.tsv file. Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit your question to present the tabulated input file so it actually looks like what it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a hash look up will be faster, you can further optimize by using the lengths to pick the hashed one.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}                                                                  
           {n=split($3,a3," ");
            m=split($5,a5," ");
            for(i=1;i<=m;i++) a[a5[i]];
            SEP=""
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++) if(a3[i] in a) {both=both SEP a3[i]; SEP="-"}
            print $1,$2,$4 ":" both }' file

col1    col2    V:159-260
```

Comment: Thanks for solve the problem. In fact, it works and print the matches. However there are thousand of rows and I would take every row without considering the previous row. The output now accumulate all coincidences in every row so the new row have their matches and the previous matches. How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Add 'delete a' before the first 'split'

Comment: I don't understand where exactly I must write 'delete a' inside the code sorry.